# libc6-dbg installation error

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to install vlagrind on my Ubuntu running on VMWare. Valgrind installtion stops since it required libc6-dbg.

When I try to install libc6-dbg using "sudo apt-get install libc6-dbg", I get this error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.11.3-3) but 2.13-35 is to be installed
```

It is clear that I need to upgrade libc6 from 2.11.3-3 to 2.13-35. How do I do it? Many packages depend on libc6.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Ubuntu, my guess is that some of your packages are broken. You should try these shell commands.

```
$ sudo su
```

Then enter your password.

```
# apt-get clean
# apt-get autoclean
# apt-get update
# apt-get upgrade
# apt-get dist-upgrade
# reboot
```

This worked for me. Good luck.